# If $p,q,r$ are all primes,and $p|qr-1$,$q|pr-1$ and $r|pq-1$,find all possible values of $pqr$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If $p,q,r$ are all primes,and
$p|qr-1$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~$$q|pr-1$$~~~~~~~~~~$ and $~r|pq-1$.
Find all possible values of $pqr$.

My work:
$qr-1=pk_1$
$pr-1=qk_2$
$pq-1=rk_3$
From the above equations, we can conclude that either $k_1,k_2,k_3$ are all even or one of the primes is $2$.
I can also get that,
$p^2q^2r^2=(pk_1+1)(qk_2+1)(rk_3+1)$
Now, I cannot proceed. Please help!

Comment: If one of the priems ($p$ say) is $2$, then $pr-1, pq-1$ are odd, so $k_2,k_3$ are odd.

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: **Hint** $\ \ p,q,r\mid qr+pr+pq-1\ $ so their lcm $= pqr$ divides it too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume that $ p \le q \le r.$
Multiplying the three relations gives

$$pqr | p^2q^2r^2 - p^2qr - pq^2r - pqr^2 + pq + pr + qr - 1;$$

therefore $$pqr | pq+pr+qr - 1 < 3qr$$ and thus $p = 2$.

By Hagen's comment, $q$ and $r$ are odd.

Multiplying again gives

$$ qr | (2r - 1)(2q-1) = 4qr - 2q - 2r + 1$$ and therfore
$$ qr | 2q + 2r - 1 < 4r,$$ i.e. $ q = 3$.

Finally, the last relation now reads $r | 6 - 1 = 5$ giving $r = 5$.

This means that $pqr = 30$ in all cases.

Comment: pretty fine! nice solution.

Comment: Also we can get the result $pqr|pq+qr+pr-1$, immediately from the following arguments: $p,q,r$ are primes hence they are pairwise coprime and $p|(qr-1)+pq+pr$ (same for $q$ and $r$).

Answer (score 1):

If $p\mid qr-1$, $q\mid pr-1$ and $r\mid pq-1$, then $$pqr\mid(qr-1)(pr-1)(pq-1).$$
Rewriting the right side,
$$pqr\mid (pqr)^2-pqr(p+q+r)+pq+qr+pr-1,$$
so certainly
$$pqr\mid pq+qr+pr-1,$$
which implies $pqr\leq pq+qr+pr-1$.

Observe that the RHS will be smaller then the LHS in most cases. This gives many limitations on $p$, $q$ and $r$.

Comment: how $pqr|pq+pr+pr$?

Comment: and does the implication lead any solution?

Comment: I edited my answer. I think you can continue from there, knowing that $pqr\leq pq+qr+pr-1$. I left the rest to you as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Wlog $\, p<q<r,\ $ else, $ $ e.g. $\ q=p\mid qr\!-\!1\, \Rightarrow\, q\mid 1\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$

$p,q,r\mid n=qr\!+\!pr\!+\!pq\!-\!1 \,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}pqr\mid n<\color{#c00}3qr \,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{p=2}$

$\ \ \ q,r\mid n\ \ \ \,=\,\ \ \ \color{#c00}2r\!+\!\color{#c00}2q\!-\!1\ \,\Rightarrow\,\  \color{#0a0}qr\mid n\, <\, \color{#0a0}4r\ \Rightarrow\  \color{#0a0}{q=3}$

$\quad\ \ r\mid pq\!-\!1=5\,\Rightarrow\, r=5\ \ \ $  **QED**