# find the number of ordered triples $(x,y,z)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

find the number of ordered triples $(x,y,z)$ satisfying
$$x\mid yz-1$$
$$y\mid xz-1$$
$$z\mid xy-1$$
and $0<x,y,z<2014$

note: $x,y,z$ are integers

I found $(2,3,5)$ as one set of solution (actually $6$), and I tried change $$x\mid yz-1\Longrightarrow xk_1=yz-1$$but it didn't work.

Any idea/hint of how can I make progress?

Thank you in advance.

Note:I **DO NOT** want a computer testing all combinations.

Comment: The first thing I note is that the primes dividing each of $x,y,z$ must be distinct.  You can demand $x \lt y \lt z$.  Then if $x=2$ you have $z=2y-1$ which leads to the solution you found.

Comment: @RossMillikan Nice observation! But even with WLOG $x<y<z$ 2013 is still an upper-bound that is too big to enum.

Comment: That gets us to a quarter billion possibilities with the fact that only one can be even.  Even with my poor programming skills that is an hour run.  I tend to look for the shortest route to a solution considering thinking time+programming time+computer time and if I don't have a good idea an hour is attractive. If I had a way to substantially reduce the search further I would post it.

Comment: I would love it if there were a solution with one of the variables a little above $2014$ so the problem breaks in a later year.

Comment: @RossMillikan I am supposed to prove this and apparently, "I tested all combination" is not a proof. Also the question is asking for the number of triples, not all solutions.

Comment: Certainly "I tested all combinations" is a proof.  There are a finite number of triples with all members less than $2014$.  One can certainly try them all and report the result.  My guess is that you have found all the solutions and that there is a reasonable way to prove that, but I haven't found it.

Comment: Side note: If $x$, $y$ and $z$ are required to be prime, then $(2,3,5)$ is the only solution: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646205

Comment: Looks like this is problem 1339 from Mathematics Magazine
Vol. 64, No. 1 (Feb., 1991).
@jpvee $(2,3,5)$ is the only integer solution, not just prime, provided $2\leq x \leq y \leq z$. From first glance seems like that's what your solution proved.

Comment: @jpvee In this question $p,q,r$ are not assumed to be primes.

Comment: @ArnaudD. The proofs there solves for $p,q,r\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: @YongHaoNg Right, I saw that after commenting, but I was distracted by something else. I have added a vote to close.